# Write to multidimensional arrays by index

Tags: python, numpy

I need to write the processed data to a multidimensional array cache, but I don't know how to do this easily.

A simple example：

```
x = np.random.rand(5,2,5,3)
ind = np.array([True,True,False,True,False])
dat = np.random.rand(3,3,3)
```

The way I want it to be：

```
x[ind,-1][:,ind] = dat
```

But the indexing method produces a copy, and the data is not actually written in. 
I'm looking for whether there's a simple and straightforward way to do that, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`np.ix_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ix_.html) -

```
x[np.ix_(ind,[-1],ind)] = dat[:,None]
```

Another one in two lines again with `np.ix_` -

```
r,c = np.ix_(ind,ind)
x[r,-1,c] = dat
```

Another one using the integer indices off the mask -

```
indx = np.flatnonzero(ind)
x[indx[:,None],-1,indx] = dat
```